# Differentiability Problem

Tags: functional-equations

Supposing we are given relation that $$f(xy + 1)= f(x).f(y) - f(y) - x +2$$ and also given that $$f(0)=1$$ for a differentiable function then is function one-one onto?
I partially differentiated relation first wrt to $x$ then $y$ 
$$ f'(xy + 1)y= f'(x).f(y) - 1$$
$$f'(xy + 1)x= f(x).f'(y) - f'(y)$$
Equating them and then integrating them with respect to any one variable should give me function but how to take I integral here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
f(xy + 1)= f(x).f(y) - f(y) - x +2
$$
also, therefore
$$
f(yx+ 1)= f(y).f(x) - f(x) - y +2
$$
hence $\forall x,y$
$$
f(x)-x = f(y)-y
$$